# Save a PDF file generated from a WebView after picking the file with Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-intent

Context: **Android 10, API 29**.

I print a PDF file generated from a `WebView`, but now I'd like to save it to a file. So I tried the `Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` to pick the file and save it via the `printAdapter`'s `onWrite` method.

The problem is that **the file is always empty** - 0 bytes - and no errors are raised. It justs calls `onWriteFailed`, but with an empty error message.

`choosenFileUri` has a value like `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/37`

---

The method I use to start the intent to pick a new file. Note that the result of this activity is a `Uri`:

```
fun startIntentToCreatePdfFile(fragment: Fragment, filename : String) {

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "application/pdf"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, filename)
    }

    fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, IntentCreatePdfDocument)
}
```

The method I use to "print" the PDF to a file. The `fileUri` comes from the `Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`:

```
fun printPdfToFile(
    context: Context,
    webView: WebView,
    fileUri: Uri
) {

    (context.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE) as? PrintManager)?.let {
        val jobName = "Print PDF to save it"
        val printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(jobName)

        val printAttributes = PrintAttributes.Builder()
            .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4)
            .setResolution(PrintAttributes.Resolution("pdf", "pdf", 600, 600))
            .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS).build()

        printAdapter.onLayout(null, printAttributes, null, object : LayoutResultCallback() {
            override fun onLayoutFinished(info: PrintDocumentInfo, changed: Boolean) {

                context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(fileUri, "w")?.use {
                    printAdapter.onWrite(
                        arrayOf(PageRange.ALL_PAGES),
                        it,
                        CancellationSignal(),
                        object : WriteResultCallback() {

                        })
                }

            }
        }, null)
    }
}
```

What I do pick file `onActivityResult`:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return null
    }

    if (requestCode != IntentCreatePdfDocument) {
        throw Exception("RequestCode not implemented: $requestCode")
    }

    val choosenFileUri = data?.data

    // If it is null, nothing to do
    if (choosenFileUri == null) {
        return
    }

    try {

        HtmlHelpers.savePdfFromHtml(
            requireContext(),
            "html document to be represented in the WebView",
            choosenFileUri)

    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        _logger.error(exception)
        Helpers.showError(requireActivity(), getString(R.string.generic_error))
    }

    dismiss()
}
```

...where `HtmlHelpers.savePdfFromHtml` is:

```
fun savePdfFromHtml(
    context: Context,
    htmlContent: String,
    fileUri: Uri
) {
    generatePdfFromHtml(
        context,
        htmlContent
    ) { webView ->

        PrintHelpers.printPdfToFile(
            context,
            webView,
            fileUri)
    }
}
```

...and `generatePdfFromHtml` is:

```
private fun generatePdfFromHtml(
    context: Context,
    htmlContent: String,
    onPdfCreated: (webView: WebView) -> Unit
) {

    val webView = WebView(context)
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

        override fun onPageFinished(webView: WebView, url: String) {
            onPdfCreated(webView)
        }

    }

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(
        null,
        htmlContent,
        "text/html; charset=utf-8",
        "UTF-8",
        null);

}
```

---

I checked all the other answer about this topic, but everyone creates manually the `ParcelFileDescriptor` instead of `it` in the `onWrite` method. Everyone does something like this:

```
fun getOutputFile(path: File, fileName: String): ParcelFileDescriptor? {
    val file = File(path, fileName)
    return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE)
}
```

But I cannot do this since I have only the Uri.

---

Edit: as suggested by @blackapps, I tried to open the output stream after I got the `FileDescriptor`, but **I still got the same result**:

```
context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(fileUri, "w")?.use {

    val fileDescriptor = it
    FileOutputStream(it.fileDescriptor).use {
        printAdapter.onWrite(
            arrayOf(PageRange.ALL_PAGES),
            fileDescriptor,
            CancellationSignal(),
            object : WriteResultCallback() {

            })

    }


}
```

Comment: Also show your onActivityResult() code.

Comment: Didnt you forget to open a FileOutputStream for that descriptor?

Comment: @blackapps I updated the answer!

Comment: But the question remains: `Didnt you forget to open a FileOutputStream for that descriptor?`

Comment: `val choosenFileUri = Helpers.getFilePathOnCreatePdfIntentResult...` Why that? As later you declare that variable again. And the second time is ok.

Comment: For the val choosenFileUri, I made a mistake when copy and pasting, sorry. I updated the answer. 

For the "didn't you forget", I didn't open explicitly. I'm going to try it!

Comment: I tried to open the FileOutputStream, but I get the same result. If you could help me better I could make a GitHub repository with a minimal example!

Comment: No that was all. Hope someone else will help better.

Comment: I have same problem with `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/37` is a download folder, then i use library for resolve the uri with this library https://github.com/HBiSoft/PickiT, hope this help

Answer (score 1):

For generating the PDF file from the HTML content I've used this [Library](https://github.com/tejpratap46/PDFCreatorAndroid)

I'm storing the pdf file inside the `download` folder of shared storage(External). Use the below method to retrieve the location.

```
       //fileName is the name of the file that you want to save. 
      fun getSavedFile(context: Context, fileName: String): File {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                return File(
                    context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)!!,
                    "$fileName.pdf"
                )
            }
            return File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                "$fileName.pdf"
            )
        }
```

Then use the library inbuilt method to generate the PDF from the `HTML` content loading inside the `WebView`

```
//webView is the ID of WebView where we are loading the html content
// fileName : Pass whatever name you want.
            
   PDFUtil.generatePDFFromWebView(pdfDownloadUtil.getSavedFile(getApplicationContext(), fileName), webView, new PDFPrint.OnPDFPrintListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(File file) {
                    savedPdfFile = file;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        createFile(Uri.fromFile(file));
                    } 
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception exception) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Now, We need to fire the intent after getting the pdf of passed html content.

```
  private void createFile(Uri pickerInitialUri) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, fileName);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri);
        }
        createFileResult.launch(intent);
    }

   ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> createFileResult = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        pdfDownloadUtil.writeFileContent(this, savedPdfFile, result.getData().getData(), () -> {
                            showSnackToOpenPdf();
                            return null;
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

In oreo or above device, We are using the above method i.e **writeFileContent**

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun writeFileContent(
        context: @NotNull Context,
        savedPdfFile: @NotNull File,
        uri: @NotNull Uri,
        listener: () -> Unit
    ) {
        try {
            val file = uri.let { context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(it, "w") }

            file?.let {
                val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(it.fileDescriptor)
                fileOutputStream.write(Files.readAllBytes(savedPdfFile.toPath()))
                fileOutputStream.close()
                it.close()
            }
            listener()


        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            //print logs
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            //print logs
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

**Note:** If the number of pages is large i.e more than 200 pages. Then it won't work as internally it's cache the pages in the `WebView` and then load it. So alternative way is to get the link to the PDF file from the API.

Answer (score -1):

I checked all the other answer about this topic, but everyone creates manually the ParcelFileDescriptor instead of it in the onWrite method. Everyone does something like this:

```
fun getOutputFile(path: File, fileName: String): ParcelFileDescriptor? {
    val file = File(path, fileName)
    return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE)
}
```

But I cannot do this since I have only the Uri.

-> Uri contains the getPath() method. You can use this to create a file object,

```
val file = File(uri.path)
```

and use in ParcelFileDescriptor. Null-check the getPath() method.

Comment: If I do that it throws an exception while opening the ParcelFileDescription saying that the file does not exists!